# "would like you to" vs. "please"

Tags: differences, politeness, business-language

I am writing an email, in which I would like to ask for something but I don't want to be very direct. I came up with the following two constructions:

> In addition, I will not be receiving my stipend while working. So *please* consider my remuneration package carefully.
>
> In addition, I will not be receiving my stipend while working. *So I would like you to* consider my remuneration package carefully.

Any additional improvements are welcome.

Comment: Use please since it's a request - the 2nd sounds like you are asking them to consider it rather than having someone else do so.

Comment: @mgb- I also want to negotiate.

Comment: Adding the "carefully" at the end almost sounds like a veiled threat. As in "You're on shaky ground , so please choose your next words carefully."  I might rephrase as, "In addition, you may be aware that I will not be receiving my stipend while working, so please bear that in mind as we negotiate my remuneration package."

Comment: @Jim. Great. Can't believe you nailed it.

Comment: you're not contrasting *would like* with *please*, you're contrasting *would like you to* with *please*.

Comment: @Matt- yep. Edited it.

Comment: I think this is off-topic (etiquette), not English language as such.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another indirect construction, and I think the one that I would use if negotiating:

> In addition, I will not be receiving my stipend while working. *So I
>   would appreciate it if you could* consider my remuneration package
>   carefully.